# Java - "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" - Как исправить?

Tags: java

Делаю Крестики - нолики на Java,
Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Player.humanTurn(Player.java:69)
    at main.Player.Turn(Player.java:27)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

Дальше код

Класс Main

```
package main;

// import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int checkWin(int[][] field) {
        // Временно. Нужно заменить для других размеров поля
        boolean t = false;
        int len = field.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            if (field[i][0] == field[i][1] && field[i][1] == field[i][2] && field[i][0] != 0)
                return field[i][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (field[0][i] == 0 || field[1][i] == 0 || field[2][i] == 0) t = true;
            if (field[0][i] == field[1][i] && field[1][i] == field[2][i] && field[0][i] != 0)
                return field[0][i];
        }
        if (field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][2] && field[1][1] != 0)
            return field[1][1];
        if (field[2][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[0][2] && field[1][1] != 0)
            return field[1][1];
        if (t) return 0;
        return 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Face.LANG = 2;
        // Face.entrance();

        int len = 3;
        int[][] field = new int[len][len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                field[i][j] = 0;

        Player p1 = new Player(true, Face.namePlayer() + 1, 1);
        Player p2 = new Player(true, Face.namePlayer() + 2, 2);
        Player p;

        int turn = 0;
        Face.print_field(field);
        while (checkWin(field) == 0) {
            turn += 1;
            if (turn % 2 == 1) p = p1;
            else p = p2;
            Face.Turn(turn, p.getName());
            Cord out = p.Turn(field);                               //48
            field[out.getX()][out.getY()] = p.getId();
            Face.print_field(field);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Player

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {
    private final boolean human;
    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Player(boolean human, String name, int id) {
        this.human = human;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Cord Turn(int[][] field) {
        Cord out;
        if (human)
            out = this.humanTurn(field);                           //27
        else
            out = this.botTurn(field);
        return new Cord(out.getX(), out.getY());
    }

    private Cord humanTurn(int[][] field) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = field.length;
        String[] in = new String[len];
        for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) in[i - 1] = Integer.toString(i);
        int x, y;
        while(true) {
            Face.playerTurn();
            String player_input = input.nextLine();
            String[] arr_input = player_input.split(" ");
            if (arr_input.length != 2) {
                Face.error0();
                continue;
            }
            boolean isNum = false;
            for (String s: in) {
                if (arr_input[0].startsWith(s)) {
                    isNum = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isNum) {
                Face.error1();
                continue;
            }
            isNum = false;
            for (String s: in) {
                if (arr_input[1].startsWith(s)) {
                    isNum = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isNum) {
                Face.error1();
                continue;
            }
            x = Integer.getInteger(arr_input[0]);               //69
            y = Integer.getInteger(arr_input[1]);
            if (field[x][y] != 0) {
                Face.error2();
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        return new Cord(x - 1, y - 1);
    }

    private Cord botTurn(int[][] field) {
        return new Cord(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Класс Cord

```
package main;

public class Cord {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Cord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Класс Face

```
package main;

public class Face {
    public static int LANG = 1;
    public static char[] MARK = {'.', 'x', 'o'};

    public static void print_field(int[][] field) {
        int len = field.length;
        System.out.print("   ");
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.print((i + 1) + "  ");
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                System.out.print(MARK[field[i][j]] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static String namePlayer() {
        String name = "--";
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> name = "Player";
            case 2 -> name = "Игрок";
        }
        return name;
    }

    public static String botPlayer() {
        String name = "--";
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> name = "Bot";
            case 2 -> name = "Бот";
        }
        return name;
    }

    public static void Turn(int turn, String name) {
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> System.out.println("--");
            case 2 -> System.out.println(turn + " ход совершает " + name);
        }
    }

    public static void playerTurn() {
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> System.out.println("--");
            case 2 -> System.out.println("Для совершения хода поставьте через пробел две координаты. \n" + "Сначала - по вертикали, затем - по горизонтали.");
        }
    }

    public static void error0() {
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> System.out.println("--");
            case 2 -> System.out.println("Ошибка: Количество вводимой информации неверно!");
        }
    }

    public static void error1() {
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> System.out.println("--");
            case 2 -> System.out.println("Ошибка: Один или более символов не являются числами или находятся вне границ поля!");
        }
    }

    public static void error2() {
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> System.out.println("--");
            case 2 -> System.out.println("Ошибка: Данная ячейка уже занята!");
        }
    }

    public static void entrance() {
        switch (LANG) {
            case 1 -> System.out.println("--");
            case 2 -> System.out.println("Приветствую, пользователь, ты играешь в 'Крестики - нолики'");
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу прощения за грязь, это только начало, много всего оставлено для дальнейшей доработки

Ошибка возникла ещё до добавления Cord, тогда там был массив, вследствие чего я и попытался изменить, добавив новый класс

Класс Face нужен исключительно для высвечивания надписей и поля, но размещён для проверки работы программы

Читал другие вопросы по ошибке, но не помогло, надеюсь на помощь

Comment: в ошибке написано, что "в классе Player.java в строке 69 вы пытаетесь обратиться к объекту, который является null".

Comment: @Wlad , Спасибо, я понял, что не так

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки были найдены, были они максимально тупые, так всё работает:

```
x = Integer.parseInt(arr_input[0]);
y = Integer.parseInt(arr_input[1]);
if (field[x - 1][y - 1] != 0) {
  Face.error2();
  continue;
}
```

Суть была в том, что string не переводился в int, я не правильно понял перевод, а так же от x и y надо было (Иначе ошибка оставалась, но строка меняласьБ если вводить 3) отнять 1